# Which is idiomatic to find out the width of country: "How far across is France" OR "How long is it from the easternmost to the westernmost of France?"

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context, idiomatic-language, questions

If you want to find out the width of country, which one would be more idiomatic:

1- How far across is France?

2- How long is it from the westernmost to the easternmost of France?

Or is there any other practical way to say it?

And another question: Does the structure **"how far across"** asks about the same thing (the width) for a country like the Sweden or does it mean from the northernmost to the southermost point of it, because it is bigger if you measure it lengthwise?

Comment: The word you are missing is distance; What is the distance from A to Z. Countries don't have "widths".

Comment: @Lambie, in which question do I need the word "distance"? I think you mean the 2nd one.? "How long is the distance from the westernmost to the easternmost of France? Is that right?

Comment: You would really have to say something like "westernmost **point**", because otherwise it sounds like something is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How far is X from Y**? **How far is X to Y**?

OR
**What is the distance of X to Y?**

[**but not**: how long is the distance]

- What is distance from France's westernmost point to its easternmost point?
- How far is it [same as above]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, I understand that the structure in number 1 "How far across is France" would be wrong?

Comment: @yunus Well, it might sound sort of informal. We would say, for example, the field is 200 meters across. How far across is the field? But not a country. How far across is the US is grammatically ok, but semantically not great.